# Perl: load contents of string into array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a simple question I was hoping you guys can help shed light on. I'm steadily learning perl.

Say I have a very large string, for example take the output of:

```
our $z = `du -B MB /home`
```

This will produce a string like the following:

```
1MB     /home/debug/Music
1MB     /home/debug/Downloads
20MB    /home/debug
20MB    /home/
```

What I would like to know is, how do I go about loading this string into an array with two columns, and n rows (where n is the number of lines in the du output)?

I was trying something like the following:

```
my $z1 = `du -B MB /home | tail -4`;
my @c0 = split (/n/, $z1);
my $z2 = join (/\t/, @c0);
my @c2=split(/\t/, $z2);
print @c2;
```

Which produces the following output:

```
1MB/home/debug/Music1MB/home/debug/Downloads20MB/home/debug20MB/home
```

I suppose I can use the substitution function s///g to substitue the directories for null values, and set the SPACE values to one array, and null the space values and set that to a second array, and can set 1 array as keys to the other.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to the best way to approach this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Diego

Comment: The first `split` should be using `z1` as the second parameter, right?

Comment: damnit thanks dirk, thats what I get for copying from my shell history :s

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
my $z= `du -h -d 1 /home/*`;
my @array  = split("\n",$z);
foreach my $ar(@array) {
my @ar = split("\t",$ar);
$ar = \@ar;
}

foreach my $entry(@array) {
print $entry->[0];
print $entry->[1];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the very useful suggestion! I am trying this out now

Comment: Hey user, I tried out this code, and unfortunately I got a list that repeats the following string for several lines: 20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/ho e20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/h me20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/ ome20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20M /home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home20MB/home

Comment: Actually, I was still using du -B MB /home. When I used your code verbaitm,it produced the following output: 4.0K/home/debug/Public4.0K/home/debug/.hplip4.0K/home/debug/Documents8.0K/home/debug/.ssh320K/home/debug/.kde208K/home/debug/.electricsheep4.0K/home/debug/Desktop4.0K/home/debug/Pictures4.0K/home/debug/Videos8.0K/home/debug/.mplayer24K/home/debug/.cache224K/home/debug/.thumbnails4.0K/home/debug/Templates12K/home/debug/.emacs.d12K/home/debug/.dbus8.0K/home/debug/.local188K/home/debug/.config4.0K/home/debug/Music4.0K/home/debug/Downloads19M/home/debug4.0K/home/ftp16K/home/lost+found

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try and store them in a hash as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = '1MB /home/work 4MB /user/bin';
my %values = split(' ', $data);
foreach my $k (keys %values) {
    print "$k: $values{$k}\n";
}
exit 0;
```

Note that `' '` as the first argument of `split` will match any whitespace character (so we make the most of it). The output for the above should be something like:

```
1MB: /home/work
4MB: /user/bin
```

You will have to work the original data into `$data` and check if a hash works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful answer! I am trying this out now

Comment: dirk, unfortunately when I tried this out, I got a warning saying there was an "odd number of elements in hash assignment in line 7." I had to put an extra space in that list in order for it not to error out. Also, the keys I generated looked like the following: e: /, /: h, d: e, 2: M, B: , 1: M, b: u. I think i need to modify the split statement a bit more before I can get it to acknowledge the space in between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you perl veterans won't like this solution much, but I basically resolved to my nix roots. I was having trouble with this earlier in a for loop, but I realized I can utilize pipes to be evaluated via the shell, so long as the answer is stored in a string.

```
my $z1; my $z2;

$z1 = `du -B MB /home | cut -f1`
$z2 = `du -B MB /home | cut -f2`

my @a1; my @a2;

@a1 = split("\n", $z1);
@a2 = split("\n", $z2);
```

Array @a1 holds values from first string, @a2 holds values from 2nd string.

My question to you guys is, is there a perl equivelent to the unix 'cut' utility? I.e. where I can split a strings output to the first tab-delimited field? This is a problem I'll have to explore.

Diego

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  If you simply want to have an array with n elements, each of which is a string with two columns in it, you need look no farther than

```
my @z1 = `du -B MB /home | tail -4`;
```

For example, the third line of your file could be accessed (remember perl arrays are 0-based):

```
print $z1[2];
```

producing output

```
20MB    /home/debug
```

More useful would be to capture each directory's size in a hash:

```
my %dir2size;
foreach (@z1) {
    my @line = split /\s+/;
    $dir2size{$line[1]} = $line[0];
}
foreach my $key (sort keys %dir2size) {
    print "$key: $dir2size{$key}\n";
}
```

which produces the output

```
/home/: 20MB
/home/debug: 20MB
/home/debug/Downloads: 1MB
/home/debug/Music: 1MB
```